# Transactions appear to be rolled back, but they are not rolled back in the database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hsqldb

PersistenceHelper-context.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">    <!---->
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:mydb"/>
        <property name="username" value="sa"/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
    </bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
          depends-on="dataSource" name="_sessFac" >  
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="configLocation" value="hibernate.cfg.xml.incDTD"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.shutdown">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
```

class header

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:PersistenceHelper-context.xml"})
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true, transactionManager = "transactionManager") 
@Transactional
public class BaseClass extends BaseTestClass{//.....}
```

And then all of my classes that I want to use transactions all derive from BaseClass, i.e.
`public class FooTest extends BaseClass`

Also, when I run my code, I see the following:

```
HibernateTransactionManager | Initiating transaction rollback
[13 Jul 2012 11:29:13,738] DEBUG  HibernateTransactionManager | Rolling back Hibernate transaction on Session [org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl@107536b]
[13 Jul 2012 11:29:13,738] DEBUG  HibernateTransactionManager | Triggering afterCompletion synchronization
[13 Jul 2012 11:29:13,738] DEBUG  TransactionSynchronizationManager | Clearing transaction synchronization
[13 Jul 2012 11:29:13,738] DEBUG  TransactionSynchronizationManager | Removed value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionHolder@17b3cdb] for key [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@14642ac] from thread [main]
[13 Jul 2012 11:29:13,738] DEBUG  TransactionSynchronizationManager | Removed value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@129a6a3] for key [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@c506b] from thread [main]
[13 Jul 2012 11:29:13,738] DEBUG  HibernateTransactionManager | Closing Hibernate Session [org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl@107536b] after transaction
[13 Jul 2012 11:29:13,738] DEBUG  SessionFactoryUtils       | Closing Hibernate Session
[13 Jul 2012 11:29:13,738] INFO   TransactionalTestExecutionListener | Rolled back transaction after test execution for test context
```

Yet when I delete from my database, the change is persisted and my future tests fail because there is a missing object from the table. Am I missing something? Any direction would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: How do you obtain Hibernate session? Are you sure that the session you use is the session where transaction is rolled back?

Comment: Are you sure that hsqldb supports transactions? Not every database supports them. For instance, MySQL doesn't support transactions when using MyISAM storage engine tables, only InnoDB and BDB. Check the hsql documentation for this.

Comment: HSQLDB supports transactions. It is ferequently recommended for unit/integration testing of applications using Spring/Hibernate.

Comment: `Session session = _sessFac.openSession();` Yet, I grab a a new session for each @Test. Though I thought this was legal since the @Transactional annotation at the top of a class wraps every method in a transaction.

Comment: Yes it does.. _Commercial support for business users of HSQLDB is available from the ... It offers a small, fast multithreaded and **transactional** database engine with in-memory ..._

Comment: OK.  Just a thought i tend to use derby for embedded db testing rather than hsql at this point :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` to get a `Session` associated with the current transaction.

`openSession()` creates a new session, and that session has nothing to do with transactions managed by Spring.

Comment: That might have done it.. Still have some stuff to figure out, and if the case, I'll accept.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used DriverManagerDataSource but I think it can have some sort of "autoCommit" property by default set to true. You can try to use real connection pool like [c3p0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/) (because DriverManagerDataSource class is not an actual connection pool). With it I don't have any problem with transactions.